# Не распознается значение Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Почему в цикле когда я задаю to="item.href" значение item.href не передается?

```
<template>
    <v-app id="app">
        <v-app-bar app clipped-left color="indigo" dark>
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-on:click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <span class="hidden-sm-and-down title mr-5 ml-5">
                TEST <span class="font-weight-light">APP</span>
            </span>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-badge left color="cyan">
                <template v-slot:badge>1</template>
                <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">mdi-email</v-icon>
            </v-badge>
        </v-app-bar>
        <v-navigation-drawer app clipped color="grey lighten-4" v-model="drawer">
            <v-list dense>
                <v-list-item v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id" to="item.href">
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-content>
            <v-container fluid>
                <div class="adm-content">
                    <v-breadcrumbs :items="breadcrumbs" divider="/" class="adm-breadcrumbs"></v-breadcrumbs>
                    <h1 class="title">Настройки профиля</h1>
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </div>
            </v-container>
        </v-content>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            drawer: null,
            items: [{
                id: 1,
                href: '#1',
                icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard',
                title: 'Панель управления'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                href: '#2',
                icon: 'mdi-settings',
                title: 'Настройки профиля'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                href: '#3',
                icon: 'mdi-apps',
                title: 'Список инструментов'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                href: '#4',
                icon: 'mdi-cash-multiple',
                title: 'Управление финансами'
            }, {
                id: 5,
                href: '#5',
                icon: 'mdi-help-circle',
                title: 'Служба поддержки'
            }],
            breadcrumbs: [{
                text: 'Панель управления',
                disabled: false,
                href: '#'
            }, {
                text: 'Настройки профиля',
                disabled: true,
                href: '#'
            }]
        })
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .adm-content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
        .adm-breadcrumbs {
            padding-top: 9px;
            padding-left: 0px;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `to="item.href"` на `:to="item.href"` (сокращение от `v-bind:`) или `v-bind:to="item.href"` - вы передаете как статическое свойство, а нужно как динамическое. Хотя в коде вижу вы `v-bind:key` - сделали правильно

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!